# undefined is not an object(evaluating 'addedProduct.price').. I don't know why I am getting this error?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-hooks

My code looks fine as I have checked states and it showing me that the item I have added and deleted in the state is fine but I don't know why I am getting this error?

In CartScreen.js onRemove() is dispatching the action which is stored in the store/actions/cart.js to remove an item from the cart.

CartScreen.js

```
import React from "react";
import { View, Text, FlatList, Button, StyleSheet } from "react-native";
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from "react-redux";

import Colors from "../../constants/Colors";
import CartItem from "../../components/shop/CartItem";
import * as cartActions from "../../store/actions/cart";

const CartScreen = (props) => {
  const cartTotalAmount = useSelector((state) => state.cart.totalAmount);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const cartItems = useSelector((state) => {
    const transformedCartItems = [];
    for (const key in state.cart.items) {
      transformedCartItems.push({
        productId: key,
        productTitle: state.cart.items[key].productTitle,
        productPrice: state.cart.items[key].productPrice,
        quantity: state.cart.items[key].quantity,
        sum: state.cart.items[key].sum,
      });
    }
    return transformedCartItems;
  });
  return (
    <View style={styles.screen}>
      <View style={styles.summary}>
        <Text style={styles.summaryText}>
          Total:{" "}
          <Text style={styles.amount}>${cartTotalAmount.toFixed(2)}</Text>
        </Text>
        <Button
          color={Colors.primary}
          title="Order Now"
          disabled={cartItems.length === 0}
        />
      </View>
      <FlatList
        data={cartItems}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.productId}
        renderItem={(itemData) => (
          <CartItem
            quantity={itemData.item.quantity}
            title={itemData.item.productTitle}
            amount={itemData.item.sum}
            onRemove={() => {
              dispatch(cartActions.removeFromCart(itemData.item.productId)); //this is the function to remove item from cart.
            }}
          />
        )}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  screen: {
    margin: 20,
  },
  summary: {
    flexDirection: "row",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "space-between",
    marginBottom: 20,
    padding: 10,
    shadowColor: "black",
    shadowOpacity: 0.26,
    shadowOffset: { width: 0, height: 2 },
    shadowRadius: 8,
    elevation: 5,
    borderRadius: 10,
    backgroundColor: "white",
  },
  summaryText: {
    fontFamily: "openSansBold",
    fontSize: 18,
  },
  amount: {
    color: Colors.secondary,
  },
});

export default CartScreen;
```

store/actions/cart.js:

```
import { ADD_TO_CART, REMOVE_FROM_CART } from "../actions/cart";
import CartItem from "../../models/cart-item";

const intialState = {
  items: {},
  totalAmount: 0,
};

export default (state = intialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_TO_CART:
      const addedProduct = action.product;
      const prodPrice = addedProduct.price;
      const prodTitle = addedProduct.title;

      let updatedOrNewCartItem;
      if (state.items[addedProduct.id]) {
        updatedOrNewCartItem = new CartItem(
          state.items[addedProduct.id].quantity + 1,
          prodPrice,
          prodTitle,
          state.items[addedProduct.id].sum + prodPrice
        );
      } else {
        updatedOrNewCartItem = new CartItem(1, prodPrice, prodTitle, prodPrice);
      }
      return {
        ...state,
        items: { ...state.items, [addedProduct.id]: updatedOrNewCartItem },
        totalAmount: state.totalAmount + prodPrice,
      };
    case REMOVE_FROM_CART:
      const selectedCartItem = state.items[action.pid];
      const currentQty = selectedCartItem.quantity;
      let updatedCartItems;
      if (quantity > 1) {
        const updatedCartItem = new CartItem(
          selectedCartItem.quantity - 1,
          selectedCartItem.productPrice,
          selectedCartItem.productTitle,
          selectedCartItem.sum - selectedCartItem.productPrice
        );
        updatedCartItems = { ...state.items, [action.pid]: updatedCartItem };
      } else {
        updatedCartItems = { ...state.items };
        delete updatedCartItems[action.pid];
      }
      return {
        ...state,
        items: updatedCartItems,
        totalAmount: state.totalAmount - selectedCartItem.productPrice,
      };

    default:
      break;
  }
  return state;
};
```

In this code, addedProduct.price is in the addToCart() which is working fine. I can add the items in my cart but If I try to remove the item by calling onRemove() then it is giving me above error. I don't why and How to solve this issue?

Comment: where is "removeFromCart" defined??

Comment: Please show us the removeFromCart function

Comment: I'm pretty sure that your action creator `removeFromCart` creates an action with type `ADD_TO_CART` so that's why that part of the reducer code gets executed but the action does not have a product property. It would be easy enough to solve if you had [devtools working](https://dev.to/dev_astador/how-to-debug-redux-in-a-react-native-app-4b19) while running your project.

Comment: Thank you all! yes, it was due to the type of action. Now it's working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was returning the type of action `ADD_To_Cart` in `removeFromCart()` that's why I was getting this error.

Before:

```
export const ADD_TO_CART = "ADD_TO_CART";
export const REMOVE_FROM_CART = "REMOVE_FROM_CART";

export const addToCart = (products) => {
  return { type: ADD_TO_CART, product: products };
};

export const removeFromCart = (productId) => {
  return { type: ADD_TO_CART, pid: productId };
};
```

So, I have corrected the type of action returned in the `removeFromCart()`.

```
export const ADD_TO_CART = "ADD_TO_CART";
export const REMOVE_FROM_CART = "REMOVE_FROM_CART";

export const addToCart = (products) => {
  return { type: ADD_TO_CART, product: products };
};

export const removeFromCart = (productId) => {
  return { type: REMOVE_FROM_CART, pid: productId };
};
```

Now It's working fine.